# vbs error Overflow

Tags: css, vbscript

I'm trying to send an email Outlook in HTML using CSS and HTML table, but I'm getting an error: an overflow on line 33. My old script worked without HTML, now I want to send in HTML. Can you help me to resolve it?

See below my code:

```
Const ForReading = 1
Const ForWriting = 2
Const ForAppending = 8
Const FileToBeUsed = "C:\link of my file"

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.GetFile("C:\link of my file")

If objFile.Size > 0 Then
  Dim objCDO1, objCDO2
  Dim fso, f
  Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  Set f = fso.OpenTextFile(FileToBeUsed, ForReading)
  Set objCDO1 = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
  'objCDO1.Textbody = "See the details of the file  ."&VbNewLine+vbnewline+vbnewline&"No more details"
  'objCDO1.Textbody = f.ReadAll
  strFileText = f.ReadAll
  f.Close
  arrFileText = Split(strFileText, vbCrLF) 'split the file content by line feed character

  For intArrCounter = 0 To UBound(arrFileText)
    ArrLineContent = Split(arrFileText(intArrCounter), "|")

    Code = ArrLineContent(0)
    Operator = ArrLineContent(1)
    CLIENT = ArrLineContent(2)
    MONTANT = ArrLineContent(3)
    CIN = ArrLineContent(4)
    NOM = ArrLineContent(5)
    PERIODE = ArrLineContent(6)
    HEURE = ArrLineContent(7)

    Dim cdohtml 
    cdohtml= "<HTML>"&_
      "<style type="&text/css&">"&_
      ".tg {border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;}"&_
      ".tg td{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:0px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-top-width:1px;border-bottom-width:1px;}"&_
      ".tg th{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:normal;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:0px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-top-width:1px;border-bottom-width:1px;}"&_
      ".tg .tg-4cee{background-color:#d91717;color:#000000;text-align:center}"&_
      ".tg .tg-g1w4{font-size:large;background-color:#d91717;color:#000000}"&_
      "</style>"&_
      "<table class="&tg&" style="&undefined&";table-layout: fixed; width: 337px">""&_
      "<colgroup>"&_
      "<col style="&width&"&: 156px&">""&_
      "<col style="&width&"&: 181px&">""&_
      "</colgroup>"&_
      "<tr>"&_
      "<td class="&tg-g1w4&">Numéro Bordereau</td>"&_
      "<td class="&tg&"&-4cee&">" & Code & ""</td>"&_
      "</tr>"&_
      "<tr>"&_
      "<td class="&tg-g1w4&">Opération</td>"&_
      "<td class="&tg&"&-4cee&">" & Operator & ""</td>"&_
      "</tr>"&_
      "<tr>"&_
      "<td class="&tg-g1w4&">Client</td>"&_
      "<td class="&tg&"&-4cee&">" & CLIENT & ""</td>"&_
      "</tr>"&_
      "<tr>"&_
      "<td class="&tg-g1w4&">Montant</td>"&_
      "<td class="&tg&"&-4cee&">" & Code & ""</td>"&_
      "</tr>"&_
      "<tr>"&_
      "<td class="&tg-g1w4&">CIN</td>"&_
      "<td class="&tg&"&-4cee&">" & CIN & ""</td>"&_
      "</tr>"&_
      "<tr>"&_
      "<td class="&tg-g1w4&">Nom Porteur</td>"&_
      "<td class="&tg&"&-4cee&">" & NOM & ""</td>"&_
      "</tr>"&_
      "<tr>"&_
      "<td class="&tg-g1w4&">Date</td>"&_
      "<td class="&tg&"&-4cee&">" & PERIODE & ""</td>"&_
      "</tr>"&_
      "<tr>"&_
      "<td class="&tg-g1w4&">Heure</td>"&_
      "<td class="&tg&"&-4cee&">" & HEURE & ""</td>"&_
      "</tr>"&_
      "</table>"&_
      "</HTML>"
    objCDO1.HtmlBody = cdohtml
    'objCDO1.AddAttachment("C:\link of my file")

    objCDO1.To ="adr1@.com"
    objCDO1.From = "adr2@.com (CCP Stored Procedure Message)"
    objCDO1.Subject = "CCP Stored Procedure"
    objCDO1.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2
    objCDO1.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "mysmtp"
    objCDO1.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration /smtpserverport") = 25
    objCDO1.Configuration.Fields.Update
    'objCDO1.HTMLBody="Image <img src='C:\link of image\ENTETE.png'>"                                     
    objCDO1.Send
  Next
  Set cdohtml = Nothing
  Set objCDO1 = Nothing
  Set f       = Nothing
  Set fso     = Nothing
Else
  WScript.Echo "no file"
End If
```

Comment: This is what's causing the error: `"<style type="&text/css&">"`. You're trying to divide the value of an undefined variable `text` by the value of an (equally undefined) variable `css` and concatenate the result to the surrounding strings. What you actually want there is `"<style type='text/css'>"` (note the single quotes). There seem to be other similar errors in the rest of your HTML string.

Comment: it's work ,thanks,now how can i exclude the first line of my file data(header),i'don't want to sent it by email?

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about, but you should probably post it as a new question anyway.

Comment: Actually my code send each row of my file in separate email ,my have a header,and it's not important to send the header to email

Comment: Just change the loop of your code to For intArrCounter = 1 To UBound(arrFileText) .... Assuming that your header is in the first line....

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers or `"<style type=""text/css"">"` if you're like me and still like to use double quotes in your HTML source.

Comment: @Lankymart I tend to avoid that, because single and double quotes are equally valid in HTML, and by using single quotes I don't have to escape them in the VBScript code, which makes the code a bit more readable in my experience.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I'm not sure how much more readable it is but I take your point. I just don't enjoy single quotes in the HTML source, I'd prefer to output is readable as to the code lines.

Comment: now the problem i' have,it's about Email signature who don't appears for internal recipients an for recipients gmail.Notes in my signature i'have an picture located on my disk